# Collect input from dynamically added CKEditors using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, werkzeug

I am trying to collect input from dynamically added CKEditors in a flask app.

Here I am creating a textarea, a button to add more fields and a button to remove fields if necessary.

```
<div class='f_elements'>
    <div id='inputFormFormalElements'>
        <textarea name="f_element[]" id="f_element[]" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
        <button id="removeFormalElement" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
    </div>
                    
    <div id="newFormalElement"></div>
    <button id="addFormalElement" type='button' class="btn btn-info">Add a slot</button>
</div>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Here is the JS code to dynamically add the new fields or remove them. Also, here I am replacing the textareas with CKEditor instances.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

let i = 1;
$(document).on('click', '#addFormalElement', function(){
    $("#newFormalElement").append('<div id="inputFormFormalElements"><textarea name="f_element[]" id="f_element[]' + i + '" class="ckeditor"></textarea><button id="removeFormalElement" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>');
    CKEDITOR.replace('f_element[]' + i);
    i++
});

</script>
```

Earlier I had a conflict when just adding new fields without changing their ids, so now I'm using the iterator `i`. I am also defining the `form_edit_list` there to store the ids of the CKEditors to be able to refer to these instances later when collecting the input (at least I thought it would work like that:/).

Below I am trying to collect the user input on the event of clicking the submit button. What I possibly need to have in the end is a list of inputs.

```
$('button').click(function () {
        
        let form_edit_output = [];
        for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            // retrieve the data of each instance and store it into an associative array with textarea ids as keys
            form_edit_output.push(CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData());
        }

        $.ajax({
        url: '{{url_for("constructions.add_cxn")}}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'data': form_edit_output}  
        });
})
```

So I thought I would store the input of all instances and then somehow filter the necessary ones out at Python Flask end. Yet, I constantly run into this error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'data'
```

I have very little idea in Javascript, maybe that's why I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now, that's I would be so grateful if anybody let's me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it should be `CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData()` instead of `CKEDITOR.instances.i.getData()`

Comment: To add to the above comment: `CKEDITOR.instances.i` is the equivalent of `CKEDITOR.instances["i"]`, ie a literal "i" not the value of the i variable.

Comment: @ITgoldman thanks a lot! I've changed that now (also edited in the post). The error still persists. :(

Comment: you are sending the data wrongly. what does the server expect? if not a string, then my guess is that it should be `data:  form_edit_output` instead of `data: {data: ... }`

Comment: @ITgoldman at the moment it expects a dictionary,  earlier I tried ```JSON.stringify``` too, but I still got errors. I'm not sure which step is causing the problem...